# is it necessary to revert something when using return inside a changeCompany

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have to add a control inside a `changeCompany()` in an existing class.

I suppose the code below is OK, but I have a doubt : Does the "return" order  imply that a return to the original company is done ?
Or is there to add a statement, unknown by me, something like `revertToPreviousCompany()`?

```
try
{
    changeCompany(companyId)
    {
        // the method will produce a message and return false if an error
        if (!this.doSomeChecks()) {               
           return;
        }          
        // much more code below
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is OK as in some situations you wouldn't even be able to revert it if not done by the runtime itself.
Imagine a callstack in which you have `try` - `catch` around some code your are calling and you expect there may be thrown an error but if the code which calls your code already established a transaction your handler is not called and therefore you wouldn't have a chance to undo the `changeCompany`

Comment: You could add that the curly braces of the `changeCompany()` statement define the scope in which the other company is used. If that scope is left (as it is done in the question with the `return` statement), the original company is used again.